# Regular expressions error message - "Out of memory"

Tags: r

I've been playing around with R's sentiment analysis capabilities and keep running into an error that is raised when running a gsub function. The positive and negative word lists were taken from [here](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html#lexicon).

After some Google searches, I found one mention of this error on the R help list but nothing else. Has anyone run into this problem? What is going on? Is there a workaround?

I've ran similar code (using gsub and stringer packages) when working with strings in the past and this is the first time I've ever had this type of error come up. Furthermore, I tried to reproduce this error by writing a similar script on a different set of strings and that worked fine.

Here is the error message:

```
> pos_match <- str_c(vpos, collapse = "|")
> neg_match <- str_c(vneg, collapse = "|")
> dat$positive <- as.numeric(str_detect(dat$Comment, pos_match))
> dat$negative <- as.numeric(str_detect(dat$Comment, neg_match))
Error: invalid regular expression, reason 'Out of memory'
```

Here's the whole 'process.'

```
## SET WORKING DIRECTOR AND IMPORT PACKAGES:
setwd("~/Desktop/R_Tricks")
require(tm); require(stringr); require(lubridate); library(RTextTools)

# IMPORT DATA:
d1 <- read.csv("Video_Comments.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",", fileEncoding="ISO_8859-2")
pos <- read.csv("positive-words.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE, fileEncoding="ISO_8859-2")
neg <- read.csv("negative-words.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE, fileEncoding="ISO_8859-2")
vpos = as.vector(pos[,1]); vneg = as.vector(neg[,1])
head(vpos); head(vneg)
colnames(d1); nrow(d1); ncol(d1)
str(d1); head(d1)
table(d1$Likes); table(d1$Replies)
nrow(vpos); nrow(vneg)
length(vpos); length(vneg)
is.atomic(vpos); is.atomic(vneg)

# SELECT DATA:
dat = data.frame(Comment=c(d1$Comment))
head(dat)
# CLEAN DATA - COMMENTS:
dat$Comment = gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', dat$Comment)
dat$Comment = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', dat$Comment)
dat$Comment = gsub('\\d+', '', dat$Comment)
dat$Comment = tolower(dat$Comment)
head(dat)
# CLEAN DATA - CLASSIFICATIONS:
vpos = gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', vpos); vneg = gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', vneg)
vpos = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', vpos); vneg = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', vneg)
vpos = gsub('\\d+', '', vpos); vneg = gsub('\\d+', '', vneg)
vpos = tolower(vpos); vneg = tolower(vneg)
head(vpos); head(vneg)

# MATCH WORDS WITH FACEBOOK COMMENTS:
pos_match <- str_c(vpos, collapse = "|")
neg_match <- str_c(vneg, collapse = "|")
dat$positive <- as.numeric(str_detect(dat$Comment, pos_match))
dat$negative <- as.numeric(str_detect(dat$Comment, neg_match))
```

EDIT:

Another error message I've received is the following:

```
> dat$negative <- as.numeric(str_detect(dat$Comment, neg_match))
Error: invalid regular expression 'faced|faces|abnormal|abolish|abominable|abominably|abominate|abomination|abort|aborted|
```

EDIT 2:

Data for reproducing error:

```
dat = c("Hey guys I am Aliza Lomez...18 y.o. I need your likes please like my page and find love quotes, beauty tips and much more.Please like my page you will never regret thank u all\u0083 <3 <3 <3...",
        "Alexandra Saturn", "And that's what makes a Subaru a Subaru", "Missouri in a battleground....; meanwhile in southern California....", "What the Frisbee", "very cool !!!!", "Get a life", 
        "Try that with my GT!!!", "Did he make any money?", "Wo! WO! BSMITH THROWING DISCS WITH SUBARUS?!?! THIS IS SO AWESOME! SHOULD OF USED AN STI THO")
```

Comment: Are you creating ~6000 `OR` operator matching - "|"? `pos_match <- str_c(vpos, collapse = "|")`

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question as it's not reproducible but you may want to have a look at the [`polarity` function](http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/polarity.html) in the `qdap` package.  You may be re-inventing something that's already been done.

Comment: The `tm` package also has a `tm.plugin.sentiment` [plugin/package](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1048) that should be quite a bit better than building giant regexes.

Comment: @TylerRinker Thanks! Wow, you've allready done all the work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the entire solution but I can get you started. I made this community wiki so, hopefully, someone can fill in the blanks...

For the invalid regex, to create an OR you need to enclose everything in parentheses. For example, if you wanted to match the words "a", "an", or "the", you would use the regex string `(a|an|the)`. If I have a list of words I'd like to match with an OR in regex, here's what I usually use:

```
mywords <- c("a", "an", "the")
mystring <- paste0("(", paste(mywords, collapse="|"), ")")

> mystring
[1] "(a|an|the)"
```

That should rid you of the invalid regex error, as your string doesn't begin with an open parenthesis and ends with a pipe instead of a close parenthesis.